# How to Replace Nulls in PIVOT in SQL

Tags: sql, null, pivot

I have the following code and I am trying to replace the Null that appear when using the pivot with zero. I do the following but it says that "Incorrect syntax near 'ISNULL'." I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Any suggestions please

```
select *
from #tempfinaltable
pivot ISNULL(sum(TotalXSAAL),0) for Section_desc in
([Communication],[Construction],[Energy],[Financial Institutions],
 [General Property],[HIGHER ED & HEALTHCARE],
 [Inland Marine],[Real Estate])) AS AALs
```

The same the dyanmic SQL I am using. The above query is just shows the names so you can see what I am working with

```
 select *
from #tempfinaltable
pivot (sum(TotalXSAAL) for Section_desc in
' + '('+@BranchNames++')) AS AALs'
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with this statement. i am having a syntax issue:

```
BEGIN 

    Set @ISNullBranchNames = @ISNullBranchNames + 'ISNULL('+(@BranchNames+',0),' 
    Set @BranchNames = @BranchNames + '['+@BranchName+'],'

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR1 INTO @BranchName

END
```

Answer (score 3):

All `PIVOT` clause must be in bracket.

The result query must look like this:

```
SELECT 
      'TotalXSAAL' as Col,
      ISNULL([Communication], 0) AS [Communication],
      ISNULL([Construction], 0) AS [Construction],
      ...,
      ...,
      ... 
FROM #tempfinaltable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(TotalXSAAL) for
  Section_desc in
  (
    [Communication],[Construction],[Energy],[Financial Institutions],
    [General Property],[HIGHER ED & HEALTHCARE],
    [Inland Marine],[Real Estate]
  )
)AS AALs
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82630/5)**

**UPDATE**

How to generate parts of dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @ISNullBranchNames nvarchar(MAX) = N'' -- you mast add empty string first, otherwise you will get NULL inresult
DECLARE @BranchNames nvarchar(MAX) = N''
.....
BEGIN 

    Set @ISNullBranchNames =
             @ISNullBranchNames + 'ISNULL([' + @BranchName + '], 0) AS [' + @BranchName +'], '
    Set @BranchNames = @BranchNames + '['+@BranchName+'],'

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR1 INTO @BranchName

END
```

Comment: If I run the following code it works:                          select *                                                        from #tempfinaltable                                                 pivot (sum(TotalXSAAL) for Section_desc in ([Communication],[Construction],[Energy], [Financial Institutions],[General Property], [HIGHER ED & HEALTHCARE],[Inland Marine],[Real Estate])) AS AALs                                                               But I am trying to replace the nulls that appear when running this query. I tried what is suggested but it is still not working.

Comment: The real probalem is that I wrote a Dynamic SQL query and I am trying to make that work. What I have above is what I printed so I could show what I am working with. How do I replace the nulls in the PIVOT with DYNAMIC SQL?                                                                 select *
from #tempfinaltable
pivot ISNULL(sum(TotalXSAAL),0) for Section_desc in
' + '('+@BranchNames++')) AS AALs'

Comment: The Query that you have provided, Hamlet, is not doing what I am trying to do. I am trying to show for each section, the number loss by zones. Your query shows the total loss for each section. My query shows the number loss for each section by zones. Just want to replace the null with zero.

Comment: I am confused. I am not really understand this very well.

Comment: @user2029109 `@BranchNames` is comma seperated list of pivoted columns ([Communication],[Construction], ...) you must generate @BranchNamesWrappedByISNULL like this (ISNULL([Communication], 0) AS [Communication],ISNULL([Construction], 0) as [Construction], ...) abd put it in main SELECT list.

Comment: Thanks Hamlet. I figured out a way to do. I created a table that contains the information when using the pivot. How do I change the nulls to zero in each column with dynamic query? I have the names of the columns in my variable @BranchNames. I don't want to hardcore the columns.

Comment: @user2029109 It is not hardcoded, just shown result of dynamically created query. Do you read my last comment?

Comment: First I want to say thanks for being patient since I am new to SQL query and second I am a bit confused on what you are trying to say? I am not sure what you mean by @BranchNamesWrappedByISNULL

Comment: So in my Dynamic query where is stated: select *
from #tempTotalXSAALZONE
pivot (sum(TotalXSAAL) for Section_desc in
' + '('+@BranchNames++')) AS TOTAL'                                                                        
Do I use IsNull around +@BranchNames++

Comment: @user2029109  OK. Does you dynamically generate `@BranchNames` which contains comma separated list of columns? Now, you can generate another list too, which must contain same list where columns name wrapped by ISNUL like this `(ISNULL([Communication], 0) AS [Communication],ISNULL([Construction], 0) as [Construction], ...)` name it `@NewList`. Now you can generate your result query like this `sqlQuery = "SELECT " + @NewList + " FROM #tempfinaltable PIVOT(
  SUM(TotalXSAAL) for Section_desc in (" + @BranchNames + "))AS AALs"`

Comment: I totally UNDERSTAND!! Thanks. I'll try to do what you are saying now and see if it works and I'll let you know.

Comment: ,can you tell what is wrong with this syntax: Set ATISNullBranchNames = ATISNullBranchNames + 'ISNULL('+(ATBranchNames+',0),' I couldn't use the AT sign because the site was giving me issues. So instead of the AT sign, I just wrong AT

Comment: @user2029109 Look at closer. `@BranchName` is a list of columns, you must wrap **each** column by `ISNULL`.

Comment: I posted my question on the top. I wanted to show you what I was doing. At the top I asked: Can you tell me what's wrong with this statement. i am having a syntax issue: (my code). Can you look at my code and see what the issue. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I thought I was wrapping each column but Isnull?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace **`NULL`** from PIVOT TABLE with empty string then

```
ISNULL ( CAST (SUM(UnitPrice]) as NVARCHAR),'')
```

This Converts the SUM value of UnitPrice to VARCHAR AND then replaces it with an empty string using ISNULL