# How to Replace nulls in Pivot using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, null, pivot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Replace Nulls in PIVOT in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626372/how-to-replace-nulls-in-pivot-in-sql)

I am using the following Dynamic SQL:

```
 select *
    from #tempfinaltable
    pivot (sum(TotalXSAAL) for Section_desc in
    ' + '('+@BranchNames++')) AS AALs'
```

This is the same as the above query

```
select *
from #tempfinaltable
pivot (sum(TotalXSAAL) for Section_desc in
([Communication],[Construction],[Energy],[Financial Institutions],
 [General Property],[HIGHER ED & HEALTHCARE],
 [Inland Marine],[Real Estate])) AS AALs
```

What I would like to do is replace the nulls with zero when I run this query.

I tried using ISNULL so that I can replace it by zero but it is not working. Say incorrect syantax near IsNull. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
select *
from #tempfinaltable
pivot IsNull((sum(TotalXSAAL),0) for Section_desc in
([Communication],[Construction],[Energy],[Financial Institutions],
 [General Property],[HIGHER ED & HEALTHCARE],
 [Inland Marine],[Real Estate])) AS AALs
```

I tried doing this as well but it didn't work either.

```
select Section_Desc, Zone, ISNULL(Sum(TotalXSAAL),0)
from #tempfinaltable
pivot (sum(TotalXSAAL) for Section_desc in
([Communication],[Construction],[Energy],
 [Financial Institutions],[General Property],
 [HIGHER ED & HEALTHCARE],[Inland Marine],
 [Real Estate])) AS AALs
```

Also, I don't have any nulls in my data but when I use the pivot, the results show null. Not sure why.

```
Example Data
Section_Desc    Zone    TotalXSAAL
Energy           Zone1  0
Energy           Zone2  0
Energy           Zone10 452
Energy           Zone2  1123
Energy            Zone3 87

Sameple Ouput:
ZONE    Communication   Construction    Energy  Financial Institutions  General  property   Higher Ed & Healthcare  Inland Marine   Real estate
ZONE1   10221   NULL    42124   89214211    911243  NULL    123120  1234235
```

The answer to this is here: 
[How to Replace Nulls in PIVOT in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626372/how-to-replace-nulls-in-pivot-in-sql)

Comment: Need to see some sample data to understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Prep the data in your temp table before pivoting on it.

```
ISNULL(FieldName, '0') as FieldName
```

Comment: I tried it that way but it didn't work.

Comment: Where are your NULLS coming from then?  Can you give a sample of the temp table?

Comment: I am not sure. When I use the Pivot, the nulls appear. I think it has to do with my data. For certain zones, the section may not appear to have any losses so I guess it puts a null there by default.

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample of the temp table?  To see the structure with some data in it would be of great help.  You change the values if it has sensitive info in it.  We can still find the issue.

Comment: I just showed the Sample output and data above in my question

Comment: I figured out a way to do. I created a table that contains the information when using the pivot. How do I change the nulls to zero in each column with dynamic query? I have the names of the columns in my variable @BranchNames

Comment: Right, so whatever script is populating the TEMP table, that needs to have the ISNULL() functions in it so the data is "clean" when you pivot on it.  I don't know how do it with a dynamic query.  The best bet is to tackle the source data.  Your query is working on the data AFTER it retrieves it from the temp table, not before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626372/how-to-replace-nulls-in-pivot-in-sql

Comment: I got it to work. The answer is posted in my question and the link is provided.

Comment: Glad you got it to work but just FYI, you shouldn't have created a duplicate of your question.